# Make tmux block until program completes

Tags: tmux

I am impressed by tmux's remote control features:

```
tmux new-window -t p12346 'echo foo;sleep 10'
```

This creates a new window in the session named p12346 and does not print anything on the screen. That is great. But how can I tell the above command to wait until the sleep finishes before returning? I.e. I want this do the same but to take 10 seconds to execute:

```
time tmux new-window -t p12346 'echo foo;sleep 10'
```

**Background**

If this is viable then it might become a feature of GNU Parallel: The jobs currently running can be accessed as each their window through `tmux`, so you can follow the progress of each job in real time.

So `tmux` will not be run in the foreground: The user will need to attach to it.

Answer (score 9):

*tmux* 1.8 introduced the `wait-for` command that can help do what you want:

```
time tmux new-window -t p12346 'echo foo;sleep 10;tmux wait-for -S p12346-neww-done' \; \
          wait-for p12346-neww-done
```

The “channel” name (`p12346-neww-done` in the example above) can be anything you like (as long as it is the same in both places; if you anticipate multiple potentially simultaneous invocations, then you will probably also want to use a unique value for each invocation). The important part is that you “wait for” the signal after the `new-window` command (as a part of the same *tmux* command, thus the escaped semicolon: *tmux* needs to process it, not the shell) and to send the signal as the last step of the window’s command.

If you need to be a bit more robust against your command sequence aborting in an ugly or inconvenient way, then you might try using a shell trap to send the signal (rearranged a bit for readability(?)):

```
time \
tmux new-window -t p12346 '
       trap "tmux wait-for -S p12346-neww-done" 0
       echo foo
       sleep 10
       ' \; wait-for p12346-neww-done
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find the following alternative approach more suitable:

Outside tmux:

```
mkfifo fifo && tmux new -d '(echo foo;sleep 3) 9> fifo' && time cat fifo
```

Inside tmux:

```
mkfifo fifo && tmux new-window '(echo foo;sleep 10) 9> fifo' && cat fifo
```

One distinction from `wait-for` is that this approach operates as a dead man's switch: it will work even if, for some reason, the `wait-for -S` command never gets to run.

Another distinction is that this will wait for all child processes of the main process to exit (unless they explicitly close other file descriptors, which is common for programs that try to put themselves in the background).

Explanation: The `cat` command will wait until something opens the other end of the FIFO, and then exit when *all* instances of that file descriptor are closed, which will happen when all processes holding it exit. The effect propagates to child processes thanks to the property of file descriptors that, by default, child processes inherit open file descriptors of the parent.